# AWS Application Load Balancer: Re-routing requests to non-approved paths

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-alb

I have a use case where I would like all requests to start with a prefix like:

```
https://WHATEVER/pfx
```

For example https://WHATEVER/pfx/a and https://WHATEVER/pfx/b/c/d

But I wish to prevent https://WHATEVER/somewhere_else and similar requests that do not include the prefix (pfx). In preventing this, I'd like to simply redirect all such requests to https://WHATEVER/pfx (home page)

Is this possible with AWS ALB?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You would create a rule that forwards traffic that matches the pattern "https://whatever/pfx/*" and probably also "https://whatever/pfx" to your target group. The second pattern can be included in the same rule and is intended to match the target without the trailing slash.

Then you would create another rule **below** that rule with the pattern "http://whatever/*" with an action of redirect and a target of "https://whatever/pfx"

Finally you need to figure out what to do with the default. It sounds like redirecting to "https://whatever/pfx" may be the behavior you want. So you may be able to omit the second rule and just configure the default behavior.

You may also want to consider a rule that redirects http://whatever/* to https://whatever/ if users may hit your site without "s" in https.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll give it a try, but two questions: (1) I assume you meant [... below that rule with the pattern "https ] not "http and (2) I want to make sure I understand your point about "the default" -- what do you mean by default? Thx!

Comment: Actually, no need to reply -- I realized you meant "/" as default (at least I'm guessing you did). In any case, works just great, the rule precedence thing accomplishes the main goal!